# Is there any app to track the road traveled?

Tags: electronic-items, mobile-apps

I'm looking for an app which, when when enabled, will

- Wake up every X units of time and record my GPS coordinates.
- Plot on a map where I have been in the past

I did an extensive research to find such an app and majority of what I found were about managing future trips, flights, etc. or about calories burned but not about presenting whereabouts of the past (on a map).

I'm assuming that my search wasn't exhaustive and just hoping that you could point something out.

Wouldn't it be great to see routes of your past road trips, ferry rides, train journeys, hikes, etc. plotted on map?

Comment: You've received a few answers. Perhaps if you explain which of them don't suit you and why, someone could help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm installing these apps. I will post updates soon.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an Android phone the easiest way is to use Google's location history. You might already have it enabled. See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/195647/googles-location-history-is-still-recording-your-every-move/).

The iphone has a [similar facility](http://metro.co.uk/2014/09/28/how-your-iphone-has-been-tracking-your-every-move-in-secret-4884687/) apparently.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that what you're looking for is something like [Fog of World](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fog-of-world/id505367096?mt=8) (for iOS). It's perhaps a bit too much like a game, where you 'unfog' a map of the world as you move around.

There are a few other apps out there that work similarly. Fog of World is 5 bucks, but there's also a free competitor for iOS. However, I can't now remember the name of that app.

For Android, there is [Umbra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.unchiujar.umbra2).

(There's also [SeekNYC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/seeknyc-uncover-your-city/id1060650721?mt=8), just for New York.)

Answer (score 3):

[Moves](https://moves-app.com) is an app which does what you want. It's not apparent from the home page, but on the [iOS site](https://appsto.re/us/PNDwE.i) you can see the mapping feature at work.

Answer (score 2):

For Android, if you'd prefer to do it with free software and not involve google, [OSMTracker](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=osmtracker&fdid=me.guillaumin.android.osmtracker) works for me, and does what it sounds like you want.  I've not used it in a motor vehicle, but I've often used it to track a day's hiking (with a view to comparing what I'd travelled with the underlying map, and adding any missing paths to OSM).